# SCRIPT DIFFERENT when run from BUTTON or SCRIPTEDITOR

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I made a simple script that duplicates two columns basically.
When I run it from the scripteditor I get the correct result, but when I apply this script to a button suddenly it's broken...

[image: Running script]

this is the code:

```html
function DuplicateSelectedRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //Insert rows 
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumns("4");
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumns("4");
  
  // merge cells top
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:E2').activate()
  .mergeAcross();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3:E3').activate()
  .mergeAcross();
  
  //paste values in newly created rows
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4:C20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("D4:E20"));
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:C3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("D3:E3"));
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:C2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("D2:E2"));
  
  // clear data new training
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5:C20').clearContent();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script editor, you are running the script 'DuplicateSelectedRows' but on your button, you are running the script 'NewTraining'

Answer (score 0):

Although it says "Assign script" what you actually need to put is the name of the Apps Script function you want to link to the image [1], in this case you have to put 'DuplicateSelectedRows'.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets